# Speed up VBA loop and avoid StatusBar Freezing

Tags: vba, excel

I've wrote this lopp:

```
ReDim TempTableID(1 To records, 1 To 1) As Variant
ReDim TempID(1 To lastrow + 13, 1 To 1) As Variant
    TempID = OppsClosed.Range("A14:A" & lastrow + 13).Value2
    k = 1

    For i = 1 To records
        'Progress bar
        Application.StatusBar = "Progress: " & i & " of " & records + 1 & ": " & Format(i / (records + 1), "0%")
        DoEvents 'Used to prevent Progress bar freezing

            TempTableID(i, 1) = TempID(k, 1)
            'TempTableID(i, 1) = OppsClosed.Range("A13").Offset(k, 0).Value2

            variable = i / nHeader

            If Fix(variable) = variable Then
                k = k + 1
            End If

    Next i
```

Where `records` = 1'000'000. The loops takes an huge amount of time (1.5h) therefore I need to speed it up. When `records` was around 40'000 I added DoEvents to avoid status bar freezing and let the user feel that the loop was running. Of course I understand that this slows down the process.

The question is: "*How can I speed it up avoiding statusbr freeze?*"

**P.s In plain english, the code simply takes `lastrow` elements from the first vector array `[lastrow  x 1]` and replicate `nHeader-times` each of the `lastrow` elements in the first array. The resulting array is `[lastrow*nHeader x 1]`**

Comment: You could possibly speed it up through this line: `TempTableID(i, 1) = OppsClosed.Range("A13").Offset(k, 0).Value2`.  Could you move the whole required range ( A13:A1000000 - or whatever the final range is) into an array in one hit and then cycle through the array.  Would be much faster than referencing the spreadsheet on each iteration.

Comment: Thanks. I tried to put the first range that is almost 14'000 to an Array and then avoid the reference to the spreadsheet but the speed is almost the same...

Comment: You could as a poor man solution, use some modulo on `i` and an `if` to do `DoEvents` less often

Comment: Thanks. I added an `If` condition to update the progress bar and do a `DoEvents` every 100 unit of `i`. But this didn't help so much :(

Comment: *There's no need to update the statusbar on every single pass though the loop* - just update every 1000'th or so passes (look at your total number of records and make a suitable interval)

Comment: a doevents every 100 is too much on a million loop (makes it 10 000 doevents for a percentage show) so, make it every 10 000 only.   also, refresh statusbar only at the same time as the doevents. Doest TempID really need to be 2 dimensional and declared as variant? just thinking...

Comment: @PatrickLepelletier Damm, now with `DoEvent` each 10000 is lightning fast! Thanks! I'll look in to the `TempID` ;)

Comment: @PatrickLepelletier Regarding avoid `Variant` my problem is that `TempID = OppsClosed.Range("A14:A" & lastrow + 13).Value` return a Variant/Double array. Of course if I declare `TempID` as `Double` VBA return TypeMismatch. Am I forced to loop trough the cells?